# Applying KnownTypes to class itself instead of service/contract

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, deserialization

As per MSDN KnownTypes Specifies known types to be used by a service when serializing or deserializing.
I am trying to serialize using **DataContractSerializer**.

```
[KnownType(typeOf(A))]
Class A: ISomeInterface
{

}

Class B: 
{
   public A{get;Set;}
}
```

Its working fine when I am serializing but throws below exception while 
deserializing.

Error in line 1 position 420. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:anyType' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SCS.Domain.FormsAndRecordsManagement.Contract.Base:A'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'A' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in a wrong way. KnownType allows you to specify, in advance, the types that should be included for consideration during deserialization.

> [KnownType(typeOf())] attribute is use as annotation to include the other dependency of contract with other object.

Sample, if class B has dependency to class A you should annotate class B like this way:

```
[DataContract]
public class A : ISomeInterface
{

}

[KnownType(typeOf(A))]
[DataContract]
public Class B: 
{
   [DataMember]
   public A { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I am wondering why it is allowing it to serialize and throwing error while serializing!!!

Comment: It is because under the hood is can't identity what should be included upon receiving the message for deserialization. The only it knows is the first level class.

Comment: Sorry , Can't get you, Please provide if have any reference?

Comment: This is the references. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751512%28v=vs.110%29.aspx